# Pandas: Find duplicates in subset where order doesn't matter and combine them

Tags: python, pandas

What is the proper way to go from a df like this:

```
>>>df
   treatment   mutation_1    mutation_2    resistance    frequency
0      a         hpc            abc            1.2           3
1      a         awd            jda            2.1           4
2      b         abc            hpc            1.2           5
```

To this:

```
       mutation_1   mutation_2   resistance   frequency_a   frequency_b 
0         hpc          abc           1.2          3              5
1         awd          jda           2.1          4              0
```

Please notice that the order in columns `a & b` does not matter.

Edit: Changed column names in my example for clarity

Edit2: I added the resistance column which is important for me to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to sort the columns of interest horizontally, and pivot:

```
cols = ['mutation_1','mutation_2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols],1)
(df.pivot_table(index=cols,                 
                columns='treatment', 
                values='frequency')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: f'frequency_{x}')    # rename as needed
   .reset_index())                                # reset index to columns
```

Output:

```
treatment mutation_1 mutation_2  frequency_a  frequency_b
0                abc        hpc          3.0          5.0
1                awd        jda          4.0          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, that is amazingly short :) My code would have been much longer and cumbersome.

Comment: I have a follow up question: There is another column, let call it "resistance". The resistance column is the same for the same set of mutations. How can I keep this column after I have sorted for frequency? See Edit 2

Comment: add it to `index` of `pivot_table`, i.e., `pivot_table(index=cols+['resistance']...`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with pandas at all